# Unknown error calling stat() against a 4 GB file on Windows

Tags: c, windows-8, 32-bit, stat

I have a 4 GB (exactly) file on an NTFS partition and a program that tries to get its size with `stat()` but it always fails with `Unknown error` (stat returns -1).

Does this mean that NTFS doesn't support 4 GB files? Or I have to use a different (Win32?) API?

Edit:

```
  struct stat st;
  if (stat(path.c_str(), &st) == -1) {
    printf("stat: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  }
```

outputs:

```
stat: Unknown error
```

Comment: Care to show some code ? Especially the "unknown error" printing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stat` function returns a `stat` struct that defines the file size with 32 bits, which means it can handle correctly file sizes only up to 4GB. You should use `stat64`.

See also the [stat function family on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: It seems you are right. For some reason I thought that 4 GB (`2^32`) should fit into a 32-bit variable but apparently it can hold only up to `2^32-1` (`stat64` worked fine). Thanks.

Comment: Though they could make the error message more helpful, something like `EOVERFLOW`...

Comment: @szx Basic math. 32 bits can't store `2 ^ 32`.

Comment: In my case, the `errno` has contained 132, which is `EOVERFLOW`

Answer (score 0):

NTFS does support more than 4GB files, you are thinking of the limitation of fat32... so thats not it ^_^